Unable to insert new item into the Tuple in Python
I am getting a Tuple in a result set. But I am unable to change the values of it later onwards. Can any one please guide me what could be the potential reason.
I am using Python 3 and I am a newbie into the world of Python. Any help will be appreciated.
I tried to modify a modify the response
cursor.execute(query)
for row in cursor:
   row['sales_amount'] = row['sales_amount']+10
   print(row['sales_amount']


The reason for this problem lies in core understanding of fundamentals in Python Data Structures. In python tuples are a immutable data structure. Meaning their value can be not be changed.  You are trying to change it. One way around to solve this problem is to convert tuple to list or specify db.cursor(dictionary=True) in cursor.
cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True)

Now you will be able to perform the modification in the data. As, dict can be updated, but not the tuples.

You are welcome. I took the opportunity to improve some of your grammar, I hope that is ok. (most of it was easily readable, but I considered the "there" -> "their"  change was important enough - they are of similar pronunciation, but have very different meanings)
